# Nilpotent groups in geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, nilpotence

I have read sometimes conclusions pertaining nilpotent groups in geometrical settings. Particularly I read that Fukaya and Yamaguchi proved that if $M_i$ is a sequence  of Riemanian manifolds converging to a single-point set (in the Gromov-Hasusdorff topology), then $\pi_1(M_i)$ has a nilpotent subgroup of finite index.

In general terms, why is this important? What does it say about the geometry (or topology) of $M_i$? I don't really have a deep understanding of nilpotent groups, other than the definition and I would like to know what is the geometrical meaning of results concerning these.

Comment: You should probably check out smooth infinitesimal analysis. I think 'nilpotent' has the same meaning there.

Comment: @mistermarko: no, not really.

Comment: @Chu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilmanifold might be helpful.

Comment: Just ti clarify: if I have a compact Riemannian manifold $(M, g_i)$ and let $M_i= (M, g/i)$, will it converges to a point? Can you also include a reference of the result?

Comment: @John: yes, but the correct statement of the result involves a lower bound on the sectional curvature of the $M_i$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks, that make sense then.